# previous output in shown even after state is changed in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I'm changing the states based on, `Upload` and `button_name` which in turn are supposed to show the current output.I want my `main` flow to be invoked when either I upload a `zip` file or I set the `button_name` to `main` (supposed to happen when I click on the `"Continue without Downloading"` button).

When you run the below code, it always shows the both the `generate_zip` as well as `download_zip_or_run_pipeline` in the page. To change the via via the zip file I've created this `DummyFile` so the name ends with `zip`.

```
class DummyFile:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

st.session_state['Uploaded'] = DummyFile("dummy.zip") # buttom_name will be set according to the file name
st.session_state['button_name'] = "main"
```

Even after doing that, it is not working.

Full is below:

```
import streamlit as st

if 'button_name' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['button_name'] = None

if 'Uploaded' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['Uploaded'] = None


class DummyFile:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

st.session_state['Uploaded'] = st.file_uploader("", type = ["pdf", "zip"])

if st.session_state['Uploaded'] is not None:
    if st.session_state['Uploaded'].name.endswith(".zip"):
        st.session_state['button_name'] = "main"

    elif st.session_state['Uploaded'].name.endswith(".pdf"):
        st.session_state['button_name'] = "generate_zip"


if st.session_state['button_name'] == "main": # this is the flow which is invoked on uploading zip file 
    st.markdown("main")


if st.session_state['button_name'] == "generate_zip" :
        st.markdown("generate_zip")
        st.session_state['button_name'] = "download_zip_or_run_pipeline"
 
if st.session_state['button_name'] == "download_zip_or_run_pipeline":
    col3, col4  = st.columns(2)

    with col3:
        if st.button("Continue without Downloading"):
            st.session_state['Uploaded'] = DummyFile("dummy.zip") # buttom_name will be set according to the file name
            st.session_state['button_name'] = "main"
            
            st.markdown("download_zip_run_pipeline")

    with col4:
        if st.button("Download Zip images"):
            with open(st.session_state['zipped_path'], 'rb') as file_data:
                st.download_button('Download Zipped Images', file_data, file_name = data, on_click=clear)

st.write(st.session_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
# buttom_name will be set according to the file name
st.session_state['Uploaded'] = DummyFile("dummy.zip")
```

does not work because

#### streamlit will rerun the code again from top to bottom

and it will execute your top code at:

```
st.session_state['Uploaded'] = st.file_uploader("", type = ["pdf", "zip"])

if st.session_state['Uploaded'] is not None:
   ...
```

So the value of `uploaded` is still the pdf file that you uploaded first.

Comment: So how do I change that? Is there a way to change / modify it? If not, how can I get the desired functionality?

Comment: When the user selects a pdf, do what has to be done with pdf. If the user selects a zip, do what has to be done with the zip. If the user does not select pdf or zip, execute what is the next goal of your app.

Comment: Original flow is: `pdf -> images -> zip -> download -> filter images -> upload zip again -> final` I'm giving the functionality from `pdf -> images -> final` too in case there is nothing to filter.